# Restrict PO Box address in Address form

Tags: regex, google-places-api

I am using google place API to get the home address from the user. Here, I need to do limit the PO box address and couldn't find limiting the PO box address in google place API itself. Is there any other way to limit that PO box address?.

I have noticed regex will be an option to filter out. Is there anything to filter in API itself?

Comment: Hi ! `regex` why not, indeed. But, on which data sample ? ;)

Comment: I don't see how this is related to regex. What do you mean by "limit"? Do you mean that you want to disable the selection of a PO Box as a home addresses?

Comment: @Philippe I have added the more description.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica yes, I need to disable or filter the PO Box address.

Comment: I don't think that the Google Places API even has PO Boxes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48333646/google-places-autocomplete-address-form-with-po-boxes